# Oracle Sql Query to find ids which has value of an attribute and at the same time not having diff values

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, having-clause

[image]

Hi Team,
I need a simple query where I can the partner id with contract status='C' which does not have any contract status in 'A' and 'B'. I need to find the Partner id of row number 3 since the partner id 2 does not have any contract status of A or B. Similarly, I want to filter partner ids which have contract status 'A' or 'B' but not contract status 'C' . That is , I need the partner id of row number 5,6. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see how your rules lead you to rows 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another option is to use the analytical function `MAX` as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT T.*,
               MAX(STATUS) OVER(PARTITION BY PARTNERID) AS MAX_STATUS
          FROM T)
WHERE MAX_STATUS = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `group by` and `having`:

```
select partnerid
from mytable
group by partnerid
having 
    max(case when contractstatus = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
    and max(case when contractstatus in ('B', 'C') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

This can be simplified with a `where` clause:

```
select partnerid
from mytable
where contractstatus in ('A', 'B', 'C')
group by partnerid
having max(case when contractstatus in ('B', 'C') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

This returns `partnerid`s that have status "A", but not "B" nor "C". If you want those that have "A" or "B", but not "C", then just change the `having` clause to:

```
having max(case when contractstatus = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have duplicate rows on partner id and status, you can also use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.status = 'C' and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2
                  where t2.partnerid = t.partnerid and
                        t2.status in ('A', 'B')
                 );
```

Comment: Yes, I have duplicate rows, hence am using group by..but now it worked with the above suggestions...Thanks a lot for your answer